# Select statement joining on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns that each contain an ID to another table, I am trying to find a way to pull back the name for each of those ID's but am unsure how I can do this using just sql, and not having to run in a php loop.
N1, N2, and N3 being the ID's of T2.

```
 T1                         T2
------------------          -----------------         
ID    N1   N2   N3          ID    Name
1     2    3    1           1     Steve
2     3    2    1           2     Bob
3     1    2    3           3     Dan
```

My desired output would be

```
T1.id    T1.N1     T1.N2    T1.N3
1        Bob       Dan      Steve
```

I'm not really sure where to begin on pulling the data this way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` for multiple times

```
  SELECT t.ID,t21.Name,t22.Name,t23.Name 
     FROM table1 t 
     LEFT JOIN table2 t21 ON t21.ID=t.N1
     LEFT JOIN table2 t22 ON t22.ID=t.N2
     LEFT JOIN table2 t23 ON t23.ID=t.N3
```

Comment: I didn't even consider doing multiple joins on the same table. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only three columns?
Simply try this...

```
select id, 
      (select T2.Name from T2 where T2.id = N1) as N1, 
      (select T2.Name from T2 where T2.id = N2) as N2, 
      (select T2.Name from T2 where T2.id = N3) as N3
from T1
```